# Is there a way to make Isotope js work consistently in all browsers when added to custom Elementor widget in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I added Isotope js to a custom Elementor widget, it does not work properly in the editor mode in Chrome however it works amazingly fine in Firefox. In Chrome it makes the height of the isotope container 0px I am having a hard time trying to make it work please help.

I tried adding the JS in the way Elementor suggests but after that it sometimes work fine and sometimes does not I think it's a browser issue as it works fine on Firefox, sometimes work sometimes doesn't on Chrome and never works on Safari.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: You are right. I also tried the following code. It works fine in Firefox. While using chrome, I thought I was doing some thing wrong. Thank you.
```
var w= function ($s, e) {
    $s.find(".port-menu li").each(function () {
      e(this).on("click", function () {
        const sel = e(this).data("filter");
        $s.find(".portfolio-list").isotope({filter: selector,percentPosition: true});
      });
    });
  };

  jQuery(window).on("elementor/frontend/init", function () {
    elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
      "frontend/element_ready/widget.default",
      w);});```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the container and initialize it first. Then it will work perfectly. Within the widget use this script-

```js
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(jQuery.fn.isotope){
  const container = jQuery('.portfolio-list');
  container.isotope({
   itemSelector: '.single-portfolio-item',
   filter: "*",
   layoutMode: 'masonry',
   resizesContainer: true,
   percentPosition: true, 
  });

 jQuery('.port-menu li').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('.port-menu li').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  const selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  container.isotope({ filter: selector,});
   });
 };
});

</script>
```

Change accordingly to your markup.